# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'

Tags: python-3.x

//estoy tratando de ejutar un script de python que importa el modulo `pyttsx3` pero al ejecutarlo la consola me devuelve el sgueinte error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta son las versiondes de `pip` y de `python`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que devuelve `pip freeze`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Instala el módulo: `pip install pypiwin32`

Comment: ya esta instalado ese modulo, cuando intento instalarlo me aparece `requeriment already satified`

Comment: ¿Tienes más versiones de Python instalada además de 3.8? Para asegurarse, que te muestra `pip --version`?

Comment: tengo la version 3.8 de python y la version 20.0.2 de pip, editare mi pregunta y adjuntare una captura de lo que me pediste

Comment: usas pip freeze para ver que tiene

Comment: adjuntare una captura